# Change mysql password interactively

Tags: mysql, password

Is it possible to change the user password in mysql in an interactive mode like it one can do in PostgreSQL for example using `\password` command?
My goal is not to provide the new password together with the command like it is described in mysql documentation about how to change the user password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `mysqladmin` [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html):

> In MySQL 5.6, the new password can be omitted following the password
>   command. In this case, mysqladmin prompts for the password value,
>   which enables you to avoid specifying the password on the command
>   line. Omitting the password value should be done only if password is the final 
>   command on the mysqladmin command line. Otherwise, the next argument
>   is taken as the password.

In earlier versions you can't do this as those will complain for 'Too few arguments to change password' (thanks Kaarel for reporting this).  In theory you can issue a command like

```
mysqladmin -u kaarel password newpass
```

and then it does not appear in the **database** logs - but may still be stored elsewhere, like `.bash_history`.

Comment: In mysql v 5.1 if I omit the newpass, it complains:
mysqladmin: Too few arguments to change password

Comment: It would be nice to have an example of the new syntax in the answer.  (Something like `mysqladmin -u myname [-p] password` seems to do the trick.  I get prompted for my old password (if I add `-p`), then prompted for the new password twice.)